# GenServer timeout handler not being called

Tags: timeout, elixir, gen-server

I've got a pretty simple setup: one GenServer, a sort of cache, which spawns child GenServers with a timeout, which they handle by `send`ing the parent a message about their inactivity.

The child passes tests that confirm it sends `{:inactive, my_id}` after a specified timeout. The problem is this only happens as long as the child never receives a call to get the data in its state, in which case it never times out.

Why should handling one call prevent timeout? Is there a way to handle calls without obstructing timeout?

Full test case here: https://github.com/thure/so-genserver-timeout

Child:

```ex
defmodule GenServerTimeoutBattery.Child do
  use GenServer

  def start_link(child_id, timeout_duration, parent_pid) do
    GenServer.start_link(__MODULE__, [child_id, timeout_duration, parent_pid], [name: String.to_atom(child_id)])
  end

  def get_data(child_id) do
    GenServer.call(String.to_atom(child_id), :get_data)
  end

  @impl true
  def init([child_id, timeout_duration, parent_pid]) do
    IO.puts('Timeout of #{timeout_duration} set for')
    IO.inspect(child_id)
    {
      :ok,
      %{
        data: "potato",
        child_id: child_id,
        parent_process: parent_pid
      },
      timeout_duration
    }
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_call(:get_data, _from, state) do
    IO.puts('Get data for #{state.child_id}')
    {
      :reply,
      state.data,
      state
    }
  end

  @impl true
  def handle_info(:timeout, state) do
    # Hibernates and lets the parent decide what to do.
    IO.puts('Sending timeout for #{state.child_id}')
    if is_pid(state.parent_process), do: send(state.parent_process, {:inactive, state.child_id})

    {
      :noreply,
      state,
      :hibernate
    }
  end
end
```

Test:

```ex
defmodule GenServerTimeoutBattery.Tests do
  use ExUnit.Case

  alias GenServerTimeoutBattery.Child

  test "child sends inactivity signal on timeout" do
    id = UUID.uuid4(:hex)

    assert {:ok, cpid} = Child.start_link(id, 2000, self())

    # If this call to `get_data` is removed, test passes.
    assert "potato" == Child.get_data(id)

    assert_receive {:inactive, child_id}, 3000

    assert child_id == id

    assert :ok = GenServer.stop(cpid)
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show a minimal test case that reproduces this behavior? Did you test manually whether this works? My suspicion right now is that the test process might exit before the child runs into the timeout.

Comment: I've set up a minimal test case that fails over here: https://github.com/thure/so-genserver-timeout

In making this, I discovered it's a call to get a part of the child's state that's preventing the child from timing out. The call is satisfied, though, so I can't imagine how this would prevent timeout.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out setting a `timeout` on `init` applies a timeout that is only relevant until it receives a call or cast.

Each call or cast can then set its own `timeout`. **If no `timeout` is specified, this defaults to `:infinity`.** The docs are not explicit on this point, though now it makes sense to me.

Comment: In the latest documentation - "timeout is an integer greater than zero which specifies how many milliseconds to wait for a reply, or the atom :infinity to wait indefinitely. The default value is 5000"